# The game with the "White Lotus Stone": is there a base for it in real life?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In the series of Avatar, the last airbender, there is a game played by the uncle of the abandoned fire prince. The uncle favors the stone of the "White Lotus" to opens it (for example in book two: earth, chapter "the desert"). The games name sounds like "pi show".

Is there a game in the real world on which this game does base? Or is it a complete fiction?

Comment: I've downvoted for a total absence of research effort. Just googling the question title would give you ten different pages about [the game depicted in the show](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Pai_Sho)

Comment: Thank you so I will answer it by myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Valorum hinted me, there are a lot of websites with the Game names Pai Sho as theme.

For example [wikifandom](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Pai_Sho) has a detailed in universe history and some examples of real life games the Pai Sho could base on.

> Pai Sho bears a resemblance to the board games Go, Chinese checkers, straight checkers, and Xiangqi.

Comment: You might also want to mention that the game *was* fictional but that Nickelodeon created rules and hosted the game online

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for this second hint. But I asked for games Pai Sho bases on. The Nickelodeon game base on the series, so it is interesting (the linked website writes about it), but does not answer my question.